# The confusion with when and why we need to use value attribute of button tag in HTML

Tags: html

I came across value of attribute in button and as it was explained here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-name-and-value-in-an-HTML-tag value attribute defines text on button. And I expected that `<button value="submit"></button>` will be equal to `<button>Submit</button>` but `<button value="submit"></button>` output button with no text on it. Thus, I a bit confused with why and when we need to use value attribute for button tags in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button's value gets submitted to the server; You might want to know which button the user clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Value is the result to be posted to server when the button is pressed and has nothing to do with display text.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, ok but Why we need to post value of button to server. I thought we need to pass value of input field to server. But why need value of button in server?

Comment: You might want to know which button the user clicked.

Comment: @ray hatfield: I recommend posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

we can define submit button by two ways.

```
<input type="submit" value="save" >
```

by this method, the value will be displayed as text for the button.

But the button tag.

```
<button type="submit" value="save">Submit Form</button>
```

Here the value is represented as the value of that button field if you need to use it.

Also, someone use this value when they use multiple submit forms in a php file to identify the form, someone uses the submit button name too.

Answer (score 0):

**Value** actually acts as text when used in the form like

```
<input type="button" value="report" >
```

And acts as a value when used as

```
<button type="button" value="report">Report</button>
```